# Is there a cmdlet to map network drives?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to backup database to a network file system using `Backup-Sqldatabase` cmdlet in powershell. Is there a `cp_cmdshell net use` equivalent in PowerShell which can be used in PowerShell script?

In SQL, I use below to map network drives. How can I map drive in PowerShell?

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'NET USE \\Backuppath  "pwd" /USER:sa'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [New-PSDrive](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113357) cmdlet to map a network path to a drive, e. g. `W`:

```
$username = 'domain\user'
$password = 'password' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password

New-PSDrive -Name W -PSProvider FileSystem -Root '\\Backuppath' -Credential $cred
```

Comment: New-Object : Cannot convert argument "1", with value: "password", for "PSCredential" to type"System.Security.SecureString": "Cannot convert the "password" value of type "System.String" to type"System.Security.SecureString"."
At C:\powershell\Backup_Test.ps1:3 char:7
+ $cred=New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentli ...
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCom

Comment: I realy don't know why you receive that error - its working fine here. Maybe try this: `$password = convertto-securestring "Password" -asplaintext -force` (just replace the one line where you assign the password)

Answer (score 0):

```
New-PSDrive –Name “Z” –PSProvider FileSystem –Root “<<network_path>>” –Persist
```

Above command work when the account executing it has access to the shared path. Else, you need to provide credentials via. -credential parameter

Comment: You mean something like this ---> New-PSDrive –Name “Z” –PSProvider FileSystem –Root “<>” –Persist -Credential "Sa" "pwd"

Answer (score 0):

I used invoke-expression with net use to map network drive and it worked fine.

Invoke-Expression "net use B: //backuppath pwd /user:domain\user"